# Having trouble with handling meteor js client and server side interactions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, d3.js

I have the following scenario in the code, where I call a function from client side and on the server side that function is getting the data from the mongodb collection and then I use that data to generate a bar chart using d3 js. But the problem is I am not getting response from server to client. I tried various methods like future and fibre but still I don't get it resolved. I am very new to meteor so any help is appreciated.

Here is the client side function,

```
Meteor.call("ok", function(error, r) {
    if (!error) {
    console.log(r.content);
    var len = Object.keys(JSON.parse(r.content)).length;
    var svg = d3.select("svg")
    var mySquare = new Array()
    var data = JSON.parse(r.content);
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    mySquare[d.data] = svg.append("rect").attr("x",60+ (d.data*20)).attr("y",45-d.height).attr("height",d.height).attr("width",15).style("fill","#f7f7f7");
            })
svg.selectAll("rect")
           .on("click", function(d){
              d3.select(this).transition(1000).style("fill", "#ff0000").duration(1000).transition(1000).style("fill", "#f7f7f7").duration(1000);
           })
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            };});
```

And here is the server side code,

```
Meteor.methods({
    ok: function(options){
        Meteor.coll = new Mongo.Collection("test")
        return Meteor.coll.find().fetch();
    },});
```

Please help me solve this issue and explain how to use it for further use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor already has a mechanism for fetching data from the server, called a subscription.

You simply declare the collection on the server, and then subscribe to it from the client. You need a helper function to do the query from mongo database.

There is an article here that explains the details: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/

And the Meteor guide also has information about the publish and subscribe mechanism: https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html

Comment: Thanks Mikkel. I stumbled upon this URLs before asking the question, but I ignored it. I was coding for more than 12 hours so I guess I was too tired to understand it.